# Wordpress как редактировать шаблон?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, themes

Wordpress как редактировать шаблон если нет в файлах footer header и тд html кода родительский шаблон проверил откуда тема берет код?

Comment: о какой теме идет речь? чтоб кратко понимать вообще, что именно Вас смущает в теме

Comment: Тема university вопрос в том как при таких темах изменить верстку не именно в этой теме а вообщем